# constant time lookup for a inserted number

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have to insert K numbers which may range from 0 to 10^9. Later i want to know whether i have inserted a particular number or not. Here K ranges from 0 to 10^5.

Both the insertion and deletion have to be in constant time. I have looked at the C++ STL `unordered_map`. But `unordered_map` requires two parameters. I just want to insert a number not a `key-value pair`.

I could simply use an array of bools like

```
bool numberExists[1000000000];
```

But initialising this to false will take a lot of time. **As is said i wanted constant time insertion and lookup.**

What data structure should i use...?

Comment: why don't you use `std::vector`

Comment: @Shan i believe vector supports only constant time insertion not lookups....

Comment: @PRP it's constant time lookup by index. And as your key will be the index, that's constant time lookup. Pretty hefty on memory though.

Comment: who said my key will be my index....?

Comment: Uhm, you did? Insert the number 999: `vals[999] = true;`. Check if you have inserted number 999: `if(vals[999]) ...`. But again, probably not ideal from a memory point of view for your large numbers.

Comment: yea...butmemory complexity will be too high right...?

Comment: What is "memory complexity"? (I'm not necessarily supporting `std::vector` as a solution to your specific problem, just correcting your original misapprehension about it)

Comment: @BoBTFish the limiting behaviour of how the number of words used grows with, in this case, items inserted

Comment: @harold The number of elements is fixed: 10^9. So I don't think that can be what he(?) means.

Comment: You could look at it that way. Time complexity is also O(1) then, no matter what you do. Any discussion about what's better or worse becomes meaningless. That's not a very useful analysis, so for that purpose we should probably assume that the fixed limit does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But unordered_map requires two parameters. I just want to insert a number not a key-value pair.

Then you should use [`std::unordered_set<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set): it offers constant-time lookup, and *amortized* constant time insertion and deletion.

If you are looking for worst-case constant time insertion and lookup, you need [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) or even [`std::bitset<N>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Note, however, that the time it takes to iterate over all its elements is O(MAX), not O(N), which could be significantly worse.

Comment: @PRP That's called **amortized constant time** - the same as with `unordered_map`.

Comment: Multiple elements insertion:
    Average case: linear in the number of elements inserted.
    Worst case: N*(size+1): number of elements inserted times the container size plus one

Comment: @PRP It is fine to assume that an insertion into a hash table works in `O(1)`(unless a hash function is bad).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you for the comment - I edited to mention `std::bitset<N>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need **hashset** and in c++ it is implemented as : unordered_set. ([manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/))

Note that if you keep adding elements each add is not guaranteed to be constant, because if threshold is reached then rehash of all elements is done. However for simplicity sake it is very close to that goal.

Comment: In addition take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200384/constant-amortized-time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the memory and not have to zero-initialize it.

This question is essentially a dupe of [Data structure that supports the following in O(1) time: initialization, insertion, deletion, finding an element, deleting all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627847/data-structure-that-supports-the-following-in-o1-time-initialization-inserti)

Comment: If you think it's a duplicate, you should probably post a comment under the question, not make an answer out of it.